# Why am I not getting the listed prize money in Gran Turismo 3?

Tags: ps2, gran-turismo-3-a-spec

Is this just a bug, or is there something I'm missing?

For example, in Amateur Ring, Turbo: Race of Turbo Sports, the (i)nfo screen lists 1st prize as 1,500,000, but winning Test Course I received only 1,200,000.  Does it pay out less each time you win it?  (I don't remember if it paid more before.)  Or is there something else that I'm doing that causes it to pay out less than the listed amount?

I'm playing the Japanese edition of Gran Turismo 3.

EDIT: I've won this race several times, and the prize money doesn't go down any more.  I don't remember if it paid in full the first time I won it, though.

Answer (score 1):

If it is anything to you, in Gran Turismo, any prize money from a race remains consistent. If you get 1,500,000 the first time you will get it every time, assuming you finish in the same position.

If you are getting 1,200,000 from a race that says you get 1,500,000 for that position it is most likely a typo of some kind. I can't say for certain being on the PAL release of GT3, but that is the most plausible option.